# Get real path from uri file and upload it android

Tags: java, android, file

I want to get the real path of Uri file which will be changed into File format to be uploaded to database (data file to be uploaded). How do I get file data in File format from Uri?

```
public static String getRealPath(Context context, Uri uri) {
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
    // DocumentProvider
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else
            if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {split[1]};
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And this is my OnActivityResult code

```
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                // Get the path
                System.out.println("url temp : " + uri); 
                String path = getRealPath(this, uri);
                System.out.println("path url : " + path);
                File finalFile = new File(path);

                System.out.println("final file : " + finalFile);

                if (files.size() == jmlDokumen){
                    files.remove(tagId);
                    files.add(tagId, finalFile);
                }
                else{
                    files.add(finalFile);
                }


                String fileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                et.setText(fileName);
```

This is my error

path url : null
11-05 11:07:25.637 30476-30476/com.project.roy.ezrec W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference

can anyone help me? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to fix the issue with secondary sd cards (at least it is working on my Xperia XZ Premium)

```
if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
    final String type = split[0];

    String extDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) { //Primary storage
        return extDirectory + "/" + split[1];
    }

    // handle non-primary volumes
    else{
        extDirectory = extDirectory.replace(
                "emulated/0",
                type);
        return extDirectory + "/" + split[1];
    }
}
```